# Tweepy error 104: Connection aborted

Tags: twitter, connection, tweepy

I am trying to scrape some tweets using Tweepy, but the connection crash after few hundreds requests with the following error:
tweepy.error.TweepError:
    Failed to send request: ('Connection aborted.', error("(104, 'ECONNRESET')",))

My code is like this:

```
  for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                           q="",
                           count=100,
                           include_entities=True,
                           monitor_rate_limit=True, 
                           wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                           wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True,
                           retry_count = 5, #retry 5 times
                           retry_delay = 5, #seconds to wait for retry
                           geocode ="34.0207489,-118.6926066,100mi", # los angeles
                           until=until_date,
                           lang="en").items():

      try:
        towrite = json.dumps(status._json)
        output.write(towrite + "\n")
      except Exception, e:
        log.error(e)
      c+=1
      if c % 10000 == 0:  # 100 requests, sleep
        time.sleep(900) # sleep 15 min
```

I can capture the error with try/except, but I am not able to restart the cursor from the point where it crashed.
Does anyone know how to solve this error, or restart the cursor from last known status?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Tweepy documentation says the Requests / 15-min window (user auth) are 180, but apparently sleeping for too long affect the connection reliability (after some requests) so if you run a request every 5 sec everything seems to work just fine:

```
   for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q="",
                       count=100,
                       include_entities=True,
                       monitor_rate_limit=True, 
                       wait_on_rate_limit=True,
                       wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True,
                       retry_count = 5, #retry 5 times
                       retry_delay = 5, #seconds to wait for retry
                       geocode ="34.0207489,-118.6926066,100mi", # los angeles
                       until=until_date,
                       lang="en").items():

  try:
    towrite = json.dumps(status._json)
    output.write(towrite + "\n")
  except Exception, e:
    log.error(e)
  c+=1
  if c % 100 == 0:  # first request completed, sleep 5 sec
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the `tweepy` call should be inside the `try` block. Also, you have arguments in api.search that are not in the Tweepy API (http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#help-methods). Anyway, this worked for me:

```py
backoff_counter = 1
while True:
    try:
        for my_item in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="test").items():
            # do something with my_item
        break
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
        sleep(60*backoff_counter)
        backoff_counter += 1
        continue
```

Basically, when you get the error you sleep for a while, and then try again. I used an incremental backoff to make sure that the sleeping time was enough for re-establishing the connection.

Comment: I'm having the same error of the original question. Do you know if in your solution the cursor starts where it stoped or does it starts from the beginning? In my case I'm asking for followers ids and I don't want to start to get the ids from the beginning each time the error is raised.

Comment: @Miguel: you are right, it starts from the beginning.